# Can a chrome extension access a webcam in the background.js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

this code works fine in any page. but doesn't work with extension. is any solution to work around

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
  .then(mediaStream => {

    const track = mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0];
    imageCapture = new ImageCapture(track);
  })
  .catch(error);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow your browser to access to your webcam (and mic). Useful link: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2693767?hl=en